# Angularjs ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider the following html code:

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
    <a ng-click="show = true; getComments(article.id)">
        <p>
            {{article.headline}}
        </p>

    </a>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-class="{show: show}">
        <p>
            {{comment.text}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's say I have 2 articles, Article1 and Article2 and each of them have some comments.
My goal is to show comments for an article (from server) whenever I click on article's headline. Everything is fine with the first click (no matter which article), but if I click on the second article, both Article1 and Article2 will have the same comment texts.

p.s. => $scope.comments gets updated when getComments(article.id) is called i.e. when someone click on a headline.

I kind of know the reason of this problem but a clarification would be great and how can i achieve my goal? any suggestions?

Comment: why are you using ng-class for showing/hiding? Why aren't you using ng-show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be loading comments into the article object itself. Then change your inner ng-repeat to "comment in article.comments".

Comment: I thought of the same solution but somehow i did wrongly implemented it before. but now it just works fine. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `getComments` works, this line is all messed up and is probably the problem:

```
ng-click="ng-class="show = true; getComments(article.id)"
```

It could probably be changed to:

```
ng-click="getComments(article.id); show=true;" ng-hide="!show"
```

Comment: No its not :), Its just a styling trick, i wont just hide that div, i want to show a part of it! (I know its a bit confusing because i have not pasted all my code, but its absolutely not wrong)